# Lowest common multiple with a fixed

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let's say we have $a,b >0 $, $a>b$ and $b>c$ can we determine if $gcd(a,b)$ is greater than or less than $gcd(a,c)$? More generally, how would a graph of $gcd(a,x)$ look?

Comment: $c$ also greater than $0$?

Comment: yes c greater than 0

Comment: Then why don't you simply write "Let's say we have integers $a>b>c>0$"?

Comment: try it out for $8>4>1$ and $8>5>2$

Comment: I have been inputting some numbers in a calculator and the numbers are oscillating. So we are not guaranteed order. But, how would we approach proving that this is the case?

Comment: Pick a suitable $a$, for example $30$, draw the graph $gcd(30,x)$ and see for yourself what it looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There answer to your first question is, in general, no. For example $6>5>2$ and $\gcd(6,2)=2$ while $\gcd(6,5)=1$, on the other hand $7>4>2$ and we see $\gcd(7,2)=1$, while $\gcd(4,2)=2$. $\gcd(a,x)$ will give us periodic functions, which are especially nice and symmetric for numbers that have many divisors. $\gcd(12,x)$ and $\gcd(24,x)$ are plotted below:[image: $\gcd(12,x)$]

[image: $\gcd(24,x)]

Comment: Excellent graphs, I had no idea! To clarify on the symmetric point, they'd be symmetric about $x = a$ and periodic with period $a$, right?

Comment: Very nice!! Thanks!

Comment: @pjs36 That is right, the periodicity follows from the key ingredient to Euclid's algorithm: $\gcd(x,a)=\gcd(x-a,a)$ ($x>a$, if you insist on considering only positive integers). The symmetry follows from $\gcd(a+b,a)=\gcd(a-b,a)=\gcd(b,a)$ (assuming $b<a$ for nonnegativity).

Answer (score 1):

We can't compare them.

$30 > 28 > 15$, where $\gcd(30, 28) = 2 < \gcd(30, 15) = 15$

$30 > 5 > 3$, where $\gcd(30, 5) = 5 > \gcd(30, 3) = 3$

We could find examples where the gcd isn't any of the numbers themselves, but you get the idea.